# Where can I get a Postgres 9.0 package?

Tags: package-management, deb, postgresql

I want to use Postgres 9.0 in Ubuntu. Does anybody know any repository that already has the debian package for Postgres 9.0? Do you think I should wait for the next Ubuntu release or Postgres 9.0 is still far ahead to be in the official repository?

Thanks heaps.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would go with this PPA, maintained by Martin Pitt.

https://launchpad.net/~pitti/+archive/postgresql

(Martin Pitt is also the one maintaining the official Debian- and Ubuntu PostgreSQL packages.)

Comment: you typed faster than me +1

Answer (score 1):

Please check http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Apt
Its up since some time and offering direct packages.