# When will postgres 9 be supported?

Tags: database, postgresql

When will Ubuntu support postgres 9?

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu 11.04 currently has 8.4.7 and I don't expect that to be changed. Debian testing has Postgres 9.0.3 so I'd expect it to be in Ubuntu 11.10.

Comment: Related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/14723/where-can-i-get-a-postgres-9-0-package

Answer (score 1):

The debian- and ubuntu-maintainer Martin Pitt has very stable backports from Lucid (10.04) on.
https://launchpad.net/~pitti/+archive/postgresql

Answer (score 1):

Check out http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Apt for 'official' packages for Ubuntu.